# How to find some text on webpage and show it in textbox (or just write it out) using Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, browser, html

Let's say I have a www.exmple.com website, with some text on it;

```
Example 1
Example 5713
Example 151
Example ...
```

and so on...

I would like to create a program where the user could input what is he looking for ON www.example.com... Like he is type "Example 151", it will show in a new textbox or something that can actually store text.

Is this possible?

I hope someone can help,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, certainly. You need to use an HTML parser - a library that can read the HTML and that you can then query it for.

Two popular options are the [HTML Agilty Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (uses XPath for querying) and [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) (uses jQuery like query syntax).